# How to order by fetch column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, specifications

How to order by fetch column?

My predicate:

```
CriteriaQuery<Connection> cquery = (CriteriaQuery<Connection>) query;
Fetch<Connection, ConnectionResearch> researches = root.fetch(Connection_.researches, JoinType.INNER);
cquery.orderBy(cb.asc( /* researches.get(ConnectionResearch_.pullforce) */ ));
```

How to set select query order by ConnectionResearch.pullforce fetch column?

Comment: you mean, should i uncomment my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Join<Connection, ConnectionResearch> researches = (Join<Connection, ConnectionResearch>) root.fetch(Connection_.researches);
cquery.orderBy(cb.asc(researches.get(ConnectionResearch_.pullForce)));
```